# Remove entire object from a json array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json, filter

I have a json array like the picture below [image]

The position for marker 1 is Null, how can i remove the entire marker 1 object from the array
so i only have marker 2,3 and 4 left in the array ? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jsonArray = jsonArray.filter(item => !item.position.includes(null))
```

Or

```
jsonArray = jsonArray.filter(item => item.position[0] !== null && item.position[1] !== null)
```

Comment: hi i know this works, but i need it to be filtered based on condition, position = null

Comment: @Aaron Well position is a list that contains null values, but it's not null itself. So its content needs to be checked.

Comment: yup so do you have a solution for this, that's my actual problem

Comment: This works for OP's requirement, but will also remove positions on the Null Island, so `jsonArray = jsonArray.filter(item => item.position[0] !== null && item.position[1] !== null)` to be precise.

Comment: @Aaron It's not possible to check if a list that has values is null, or even an empty list. I mean you can check but the result is false. `[] === null` would always return false. The closest you can get is check whether that list includes null which I've updated my answer to show that too.

Comment: Works perfectly thank you Ramin

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```js
const result = arrayOfObjects.filter((object) => {
  return object.position[0] !== null && object.position[1] !== null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use a library lodash and using  [filter](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#filter)  method, like this:

```
var items = _.filter(items, function(item){return item.position});
```

or

```
var items = _.filter(items, function(item){return item.position !== null && item.position !== ""});
```

we can filter out objects which do have position null

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
const filtered = array.filter(items => items.position[0] != null || items.position[1] != null);
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: @Aaron see the answer.  I have updated